# Jolt tranfrorm nested json array

Tags: arrays, json, apache-nifi, jolt

How can I break and flatten nested JSON with arrays using Jolt transformations

from:

```
{
  "product": [
    "test1",
    "test2"
  ],
  "Purchase": [
    1,
    2
  ],
  "Renewal": [
    1,
    2
  ]
}
```

to:

```json
[
  {
    "product": "test1",
    "Purchase": 1,
    "Renewal": 1
  },
  {
    "product": "test2",
    "Purchase": 2,
    "Renewal": 2
  }
]
```

I want to flatten this array json file in order to fit to sql db format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a shift transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "[#2].&2" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where `&2` leaf separates values into new sub-arrays by going to levels up to grab their current respective array names, and `[#2]` re-organizes them to form array of objects.

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Edit : If the input is like the below one as asked in the last comment

```json
{
  "product": [
    "test- 1",
    "test- 2"
  ],
  "Purchase": [
    2,
    2
  ],
  "Renewal": 1
}
```

then you can consider using

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*r*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "[#2].&2",
          "@(2,Renewal)": "[#2].Renewal"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Re*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: What if my data is not symmetric? {
  "product": [
    "test- 1",
    "test- 2"
  ],
  "Purchase": [
    2,
    2
  ],
  "Renewal": 1
}

Comment: Hi @anton , I've just edited.

Comment: But in this case "Renewal" element is repeating for both parts. This element should be considered just for the first element. My desired output should be: [
  {
    "product": "test- 1",
    "Purchase": 1,
    "Renewal": 1
  },
  {
    "product": "test- 2",
    "Purchase": 2,
  }
]

Comment: If this is the case, tehn just convert the `[#2].Renewal` to `[#1].Renewal` @anton